# How to correctly add preset to Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify2 and have a problem adding preset to my Vue2 app. There are errors thrown up. I installed preset through vue add vuetify-preset-rally and then added to vuetify.js as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework';
import { preset } from 'vue-cli-plugin-vuetify-preset-rally/preset'

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  preset,
  rtl: true,
  theme: {dark : true}
});
```

I followed official Vuetify documentation. I got a bunch of errors, most of them are sth like this:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-29.use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-29.use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-29.use[3]!./node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been
> initialized using an options object that does not match the API
> schema.
>
> - options has an unknown property 'prependData'. These properties are valid:    object { implementation?, sassOptions?, additionalData?,
>   sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
>   at validate (D:\SalesCore\salescore\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:105:11)
>   at Object.loader (D:\SalesCore\salescore\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:30:29)

I also tried to add the whole string to preset but it doesn't change anything:

```
export default new Vuetify({
  preset: 'vue-cli-plugin-vuetify-preset-rally/preset',
  rtl: true,
  theme: {dark : true}
});
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "salescore",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.0",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify-preset-rally": "~1.0.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Why there are problems and how to overcome it? I use `v-app` in my application.

**EDIT:**
I installed some dependencies and configured my webpack through `vue.config.js`. Just copied snippet from official docs but there is some problem with this webpack (I used `vue inspect` to check if all is ok and snippet was added to webpack) - it throws an error on compilation:

**vue.config.js**

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],

  configureWebpack: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              indentedSyntax: true // optional
            },
            // Requires >= sass-loader@^8.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              sassOptions: {
                indentedSyntax: true // optional
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
})
```

Error:

> ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been
> initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API
> schema.

Comment: Did you configure saas loader correctly, in your web pack config?

Comment: @ArslanButt I did the following: installed `npm install vuetify`, then `npm install sass@~1.32 sass-loader deepmerge -D`. Next I added saas loader to webpack through `vue.config.js`. I edited my main post where I showed how I added saas loader. Unfortunately there is some error: `ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.` Could you please take a look

Comment: What happens if you remove the webpack rules from `vue.config.js`? Normally VueCLI has a built-in support for SASS/SCSS - the only thing you might need is to automatically import some SASS variables in all your style sections. If you have the word `prependData` inside your `vue.config.js` - replace it with `additionalData`